# With exactly once semantics, is the Generals Paradox solved now?

Tags: apache-kafka

Here is what i meant by general's paradox : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem

and here is the confluent's blog regarding exactly once semantics :
https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/?utm_content=buffer9b1b6&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer
I am struggling with relating the two problems exactly once semantics and generals paradox. Whether both are same or they just look like same but are not.

Comment: Check out this blog (and the references in it): https://medium.com/@jaykreps/exactly-once-support-in-apache-kafka-55e1fdd0a35f

Comment: thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're not the same:

1. Two generals problem is symmetric. Client to broker communication is not.
2. Generals cannot retry their attack, they only get one change to get it right.  Kafka message delivery can be retried if the first outcome was uncertain. Idempotency means the second attempt can be identified as retry and ignored if the first already succeeded.

NB. This read is relevant:
https://medium.com/@jaykreps/exactly-once-support-in-apache-kafka-55e1fdd0a35f

> (In addition to FLP a number of people also linked to the Two Generals problem as the “mathematical theorem” being violated. I’m actually not sure why since, although I see the analogy for a traditional messaging system, reading and processing data in Kafka is not very similar to that problem.)

Comment: this is a very good start for my understanding, of this concept. I would ask more here(may be a separate question), after i delve on it a little. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Once Kafka delivers the message to the consumer, it can't undeliver it. Message delivery in this case is equivalent to the generals deciding to attack, so I don't believe #2 is correct.